# Фильтр с помощью STL

Tags: c++, stl, фильтр

Что-то ощущение, что вопрос из серии "как я сам недотумкал", но...

Есть генератор (чисел, но лучше объектов). В идеале - как-то возвращает, что закончил генерировать (хорошо бы, чтоб можно было и `istream_iterator` передать, и лямбду, скажем...), но - скрепя сердце - согласен даже на просто количество.  Дальше - есть предикат, который в сам генератор не зашивается (а если зашивается - то мы точно не можем сказать заранее, сколько значений будет сгенерировано!)

Их хочется отфильтровать и отправить куда-то.

Частями делается просто - скажем, `generate_n` в какой-то вектор (через `back_inserter`), потом - `copy_if` с предикатом - скажем, в `ostream_iterator`.

Написать собственный код еще проще :)

Но хочется извратиться - через STL и без дополнительного хранения в контейнере. В идеале - одной строкой (один вложенный вызов).

Ощущение, что крутится что-то такое рядом, но что-то никак не дается...

Вот пример кода:

```
vector<int> v(1000);
generate(v.begin(),v.end(),[](){.....});
copy_if(v.begin(),v.end(),[](){.....},
        ostrim_iterator<int>(cout,"\n"));
```

Как сделать это же БЕЗ дополнительного вектора? Если количество генерируемых объектов может быть очень велико?

`generate_n` не годится по двум причинам: в нем нет предиката и я заранее не знаю, сколько будет сгенерировано объектов. Если я перенесу предикат прямо в генератор - как объяснить, что все сгенерировано и пора выходить из алгоритма? Разве что с помощью исключения, но это - некорректное с проектной точки зрения решение.

Свой код выглядит примерно так:

```
int n;
ostrim_iterator<int> os(cout,"\n");
while([&n](){ return true; /* false по окончании генерации*/ })
{
     if (pred(n)) *os++ = n;
}
```

Т.е. пока генерируется, просто проверяем предикатом и отправляем через итератор.

Еще раз подчеркиваю - мне не задачу решить, мне просто интересно, как ее решить, оставаясь в рамках стандартной библиотеки, и можно ли это вообще? Казалось бы, цепочка

```
Генератор -> Фильтр -> Выход
```

не должна быть редкостью, так что стандартная библиотека должна бы содержать ее решение?

**Update**
Придумался вариант - написание итератора от генератора. Т.е. с каждым `++` этот итератор возвращает вновь сгенерированное значение. Тогда хватит вообще обычного `copy_if`. Нет такого стандартного адаптера, превращающего генератор в итератор?...

Comment: Честно говоря, по этому описанию так сразу не понятно, что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Почему бы не использовать std::generate с кастомным генератором?

Comment: @free_ze Потому что в этом случае я не могу сообщить из генератора, что все, что надо, сгенерировано. Разве что генерировать исключение - но это явный костыль. `generate_n` не годится по той же причине - я не знаю, когда закончится генерация, т.е. сколько будет элементов.

Comment: Может fork + pipe?

Comment: @avp Да я легко могу свою функцию руками написать (что и сделал уже), вопрос же в принципе...

Comment: @Unick Смотрите, так понятнее?

Comment: кто сегодня минусы раздает ?

Comment: @perfect Надеюсь, вы не меня спрашиваете? :)

Comment: @Harry нет конечно )

Comment: @Harry, ваш генератор может возвращать пустоту, которую можно потом усечь. По крайней мере не будет копирования =)

Comment: @Harry, pipe это, конечно, шутка. Если не хотите делать сопрограммы (в Linux swapcontext()), то наверное нужна функция (в классе?), которая принимает фильтр, генерит след. значение, сохраняет состояние и возвращает итератор (по сути адрес возвращаемого объекта или null в конце). Второй итератор copy_if должен просто возвращать null

Comment: Кстати, ваша функция `while (...) ... *os++ = n;` она же накапливает где-то результаты, а не сразу передеает их в `copy_if`?  Я правильно понял?

Comment: А что, нельзя функции генератора передавать как-то (кроме исключения) что больше нечего генерировать? Дать ей pointer или пусть она возвращает std::pair<int, bool>, где bool будет флагом того что еще есть что генерировать?

Comment: @avp Нет, не накапливает. Сгенерировала, отфильтровала, выплюнула в консоль.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Можно. Но ведь тогда нужно переписывать операторы для вывода этой пары?

Answer (score 1):

возможно стоит поиграться с rangeV3 эрика нилберта, все-таки это когда то станет стандартом:
https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/
код нет возможности проверить, но думаю копать примерно так:

```
//взято из тестов
auto ns = view::generate([]() mutable {
        static int N;
        return ++N;
});
auto rng = ns | view::take_while([](int i) { return i < 5; }); //сюда нужно вставить ваш предикат

//ну и отправляем rng в std::cout:
ranges::for_each(myRanges, [](auto const& r) { std::cout << r << '\n'; });

//либо вроде даже так, не помню точно:
std::cout<<rng;
```

если нужны примеры, то есть в тестах у него:
https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/tree/master/test